# Read Excel file in J2ME and get data from it

Tags: java, java-me, j2mepolish

I am very new to j2me.

in my project i have to get data from excel sheet.
but i didn't get any solution from google yet,
i want to know how to read excel file in j2me and get data from excel file.

please help me out.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try third party library apache-POI